# How to replace paths to executables in source code with Nix that are not in PATH

Tags: haskell, executable, nix, nixos

I wish to write some Haskell that calls an executable as part of its work; and install this on a nixOS host.  I don't want the executable to be in my PATH (and to rely on that would disrupt the beautiful dependency model of nix).

If this were, say, a Perl script, I would have a simple builder that looked for strings of a certain format, and replaced them with the executable names, based upon dependencies declared in the .nix file.  But that seems somewhat harder with the cabal-based building common to haskell.

Is there a standard idiom for encoding the paths to executables at build time (including during development, as well as at install time) within Haskell code on nix?

For the sake of a concrete example, here is a trivial "script":

```
import System.Process ( readProcess )

main = do
  stdout <- readProcess "hostname" [] ""
  putStrLn $ "Hostname: " ++ stdout
```

I would like to be able to compile run this (in principle) without relying on hostname being in the PATH, but rather replacing hostname with the full /nix/store/-inetutils-/bin/hostname path, and thus also gaining the benefits of dependency management under nix.

This could possibly be managed by using a shell (or similar) script, built using a replacement scheme as defined above, that sets up an environment that the haskell executable expects; but still that would need some bootstrapping via the cabal.mkDerivation, and since I'm a lover of OptParse-Applicative's bash completion, I'm loathe to slow that down with another script to fire up every time I hit the tab key.  But if that's what's needed, fair enough.

I did look through cabal.mkDerivation for some sort of pre-build step, but if it's there I'm not seeing it.

Thanks,

Comment: Don't executable need to be in path in all linux distributions? (nix or not)

Comment: no, not if you use the full (absolute) name of the executable.  The path is just a convenience.

Comment: Your were right, I completely forget about absolute path.

Comment: It is my (rudimentary) understand of `nix` that it should be handling the setup of the environment for a particular program all by itself. Why would you want to re-implement that logic in Haskell? In other words, you say that you have "dependencies declared in the .nix file" - can `nix` add those dependencies to the PATH during the execution of your program? (Feel free to ignore if this understanding of `nix` is entirely wrong...)

Comment: nix will handle setting up the environment during the **build** of the program, but nothing special happens during the **runtime** of the program once installed (I believe you can demonstrate this by comparing the strings output of env, which contains strings used during the build, with the output of running env).  So my goal is to get the strings used during the build phase, representing the dependent executables I wish to run, into the executable (or possibly a data file in a fixed place owned by the executable), so that it may read & call them, and the dependencies will be documented.

Comment: What kind of script do you want to run? What is it most tied to?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're building the Haskell app in Nix, you can patch a configuration file via your Nix expression. For an example of how to do this, have a look at [this small project](https://github.com/roberth/example-haskell-nix-dependency).

The crux is that you can define a `postConfigure` hook like [this](https://github.com/roberth/example-haskell-nix-dependency/blob/master/packages.nix#L23):

```
pkgs.haskell.lib.overrideCabal yourProject (old: {
  postConfigure = ''
    substituteInPlace src/Configuration.hs --replace 'helloPrefix = Nothing' 'helloPrefix = Just "${pkgs.hello}"'
  '';
})
```

Comment: Many thanks, Robert.  Using that example, and particularly the bit about the use of postConfigure, I have indeed a working solution.  I made a few changes so that I can use the nix paths in development (e.g., under cabal repl) as well as under build.

Answer (score 2):

What I do with my xmonad build in nix<sup>1</sup> is refer to executable paths as things like `@@compton@@/bin/compton`. Then I use a script like this to generate my default.nix file:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

packages=($(grep '@@[^@]*@@' src/Main.hs | sed -e 's/.*@@\(.*\)@@.*/\1/' | sort -u))

extra_args=()
for p in "${packages[@]}"; do
    extra_args+=(--extra-arguments "$p")
done

cabal2nix . "${extra_args[@]}" \
    | head -n-1

echo "  patchPhase = ''";
echo "    substituteInPlace src/Main.hs \\"
for p in "${packages[@]}"; do
    echo "      --replace '@@$p@@' '\${$p}' \\"
done
echo "  '';"

echo "}"
```

What it does is grep through `src/Main.hs` (could easily be changed to find all haskell files, or to some specific configuration module) and pick out all the tags surrounded by`@@` like `@@some-package-name@@`. It then does 2 things with them:

1. passes them to cabal2nix as extra arguments for the nix expression it generates
2. post-processes nix expression output from cabal2nix to add a patch phase, which replaces the `@@some-package-name@@` tag in the Haskell source file with the actual path to the derivation.<sup>2</sup>

This generates a nix-expression like this:

```
{ mkDerivation, base, compton, networkmanagerapplet, notify-osd
, powerline, setxkbmap, stdenv, synapse, system-config-printer
, taffybar, udiskie, unix, X11, xmonad, xmonad-contrib
}:
mkDerivation {
  pname = "xmonad-custom";
  version = "0.0.0.0";
  src = ./.;
  isLibrary = false;
  isExecutable = true;
  executableHaskellDepends = [
    base taffybar unix X11 xmonad xmonad-contrib
  ];
  description = "My XMonad build";
  license = stdenv.lib.licenses.bsd3;
  patchPhase = ''
    substituteInPlace src/Main.hs \
      --replace '@@compton@@' '${compton}' \
      --replace '@@networkmanagerapplet@@' '${networkmanagerapplet}' \
      --replace '@@notify-osd@@' '${notify-osd}' \
      --replace '@@powerline@@' '${powerline}' \
      --replace '@@setxkbmap@@' '${setxkbmap}' \
      --replace '@@synapse@@' '${synapse}' \
      --replace '@@system-config-printer@@' '${system-config-printer}' \
      --replace '@@udiskie@@' '${udiskie}' \
  '';
}
```

The net result is I can just write Haskell code and a cabal package file; I don't have to worry much about maintaining the nix package file as well, only re-running my generate-nix script if my dependencies change.

In my Haskell code I just write paths to executables as if `@@the-nix-package-name@@` was an absolute path to a folder where that package is installed, and everything magically works.

The installed xmonad binary ends up containing hardcoded references to the absolute paths to the executables I call, which is how nix likes to work (this means it automatically knows about the dependency during garbage collection, for example). And I don't have to worry about keeping the things I called in my interactive environment's `PATH`, or maintaining a wrapper that sets up `PATH` just for this executable.

---

<sup>1</sup> I have it set up as a cabal project that gets built and installed into the nix store, rather than having it dynamically recompile itself from `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs`

<sup>2</sup> Step 2 is a little meta, since I'm using a bash script to generate nix code with an embedded bash script in it

Answer (score 0):

This is not indented to be the answer but if I post this in comment section it would turn out to be ugly formatted.

Also I am not sure if this hack is the right way to do the job.

I notice that if I use `nix-shell` I can get full path to nix store

Assume hash is always the same, AFAIK I believe it is, you can use it to hard-coded in build recipe.

```
$ which bash
/run/current-system/sw/bin/bash
[wizzup@ ~] 
$ nix-shell -p bash

[nix-shell:~]$ which bash
/nix/store/wb34dgkpmnssjkq7yj4qbjqxpnapq0lw-bash-4.4-p12/bin/bash
```

Lastly, I doubt if you have to to any of this if you use [buildInput](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#ssec-stdenv-attributes), it should be the same path.

Comment: Thank you wizzup, but that's slightly tangential to my question - I can indeed find the full paths from the environment during the build phase, it's where / how to store them such that at runtime the executable can retrieve them that is foxing me.